# The chain rule in the case of a product of multivariate function and a function of one variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Given is $F(x(p),y(p),z(p),t)=A(x(p),y(p),z(p))B(t)$

Is it correct to write

$\frac{dF}{dp}=[\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dp}+\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dp}+\frac{\partial A}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dp}]B(t)$

Is it correct to also write

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=A(x(p),y(p),z(p))\frac{dB}{dt}$

I was reading about the chain rule on Wikipedia and others but couldn't find a case with a similar product of functions.

EDIT: Also given is $B(t)=\frac{dp}{dt}$, thus $p$ depends on $t$, as shown by Fimpellizieri (see below)

Comment: Are $p$ and $t$ independent?

Comment: $B(t) = \frac{dp}{dt}$

Comment: This means $p$ depends on $t$ (assuming $B$ is not identically zero), so your second one is incorrect.

Comment: What is the correct expression for the second one.

Comment: @user142523 You apply the basic product rule, then chain rule.

Comment: I am unsure how to do this. Are there three levels of dependence?

Comment: See the edit on my answer.

Comment: Thank you both for commenting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ and $t$ are independent, meaning $\frac{d}{dt}p=\frac{d}{dp}t=0$, then yes, both are correct.

EDIT: If $p$ depends on $t$ via $\frac{d}{dt}p=B$, as indicated in the comments, then the chain rule (together with the product rule) for the second expression yields

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F
=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial t}A\right)B+A\left(\frac{d }{d t}B\right)\\
=\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dp}\frac{dp}{dt}
+\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dp}\frac{dp}{dt}
+\frac{\partial A}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dp}\frac{dp}{dt}\right)B+A\cdot B'\\
=\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dp}
+\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dp}
+\frac{\partial A}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dp}\right)B^2+A\cdot B'$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to have helped.